# How can I consolidate two drives into one bigger drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, windows

I have two 500 GB SSDs running Windows and xubuntu. The prices of flash nand is dropping, so I was considering getting a 1TB M.2 SSD instead. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to move my existing partitions over to the new drive and dual boot from it.

I found an answer to this question before but it doesn't really make too much sense to me.

Thanks,
djtravz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `dd` is the tool you are looking for.. https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd

Just create two new partitions on the new drive, and use dd to copy them over.

```
dd if=/path/to/firstDirve of=/path/to/m.2DrivePartition1 bs=1M
dd if=/path/to/SndDrive   of=/path/to/m.2DrivePartition2 bs=1M
```

ie

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/nvme0n1p1 bs=1M
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/nvme0n1p2 bs=1M
```

`bs=1M` ensures that you copy your data in large chunks

For Completeness (from the comments)
You are also able to use gparted to copy and partitions around, this should be fairly straightforward here is a pretty looking page :) that tells you how https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/03/copy-partitions-with-gparted/

Comment: Two things:
1. Could I use gParted instead? Do they work differently or not?
2. How would I boot into the different drives?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with gparted (I never really liked the gui or gui's in general for tasks meant to be done on the command line) but yes you are able to copy partitions using gparted, it should be pretty straight forward in the gui

Comment: @j-money Your second command will overwrite the first command's data in the order you've provided.  Which means they'll lose their first partition's data if they do it this way.

Comment: yes as I have it written it will overwrite the aforementioned data, however I made an assumption that given the man page and some thinking they would be able to extapolate the information needed not to do this. I will update the answer to reflect the more correct way (to not lose data)